# Spring 4 submodule annotaions

Tags: spring, module, annotations, spring-boot

I am using Spring 4.x for my latest project, no xml, only annotations. It was working fine till I decided to move part of my project into a submodule. I see the submodule jar in the lib folder of the project jar (used spring boot jar maven plugin to package).
The problem now is that Spring does not recognize the components in the submodule jar. The package names are the same for both the jars.

```
sample code
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={JmsTemplateAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.abc")
Structure
project.jar+
           |-lib+
                |-submodule.jar
```

Spring loads all the beans / components in the project for that package, but nothing from the embedded jar file.
Stacktrace excerpt:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.abc.xxxx] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency....
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Both projects are Spring Boot projects?

Comment: The class you except to be automatically picked up from the dependent jar has the correct annotation on it?

Comment: Only the main project is a Spring-boot project. The sub-module does not have a main class. Also, neither use spring-boot-starter-parent as the parent. The class that I expect to be picked up was there in the main project before I moved it to the sub-module.

Comment: What I meant to say is that it has the Component(value="uvr") annotation and I am injecting it using Autowired and redundant @Qualifier("uvr")

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great idea to split packages across multiple jar files. I imagine it will work if you name the packages uniquely. Please raise an issue in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) if you think it might be fixable in the class loader.

Comment: I am using the top level package for ComponentScan. i.e. com.abc. I have also tried the @ComponentScan({"com.abc.server","com.abc.lib"}) which are the respective packages in the main project and the submodule.

Comment: I didn't mean the component scan. You can put that on any package you like (except the default package, and I suppose I wouldn't recommend "com" or "org" either). I meant the classes themselves - are they in the same package in 2 different jars?

Comment: No, that is not the case. I did not split the same package. The two modules have classes in different packages.

Comment: Can you share a minimal project that reproduces the problem then please?

Comment: It turned out to be a trivial issue. I have fixed it, will delete the post.